# Replace a character at a specific location in a string

Tags: go

I know about the method `string.Replace()`. And it works if you know exactly what to replace and its occurrences. But what can I do if I want to replace a char at only a known position? I'm thinking of something like this:

```
randLetter := getRandomChar()

myText := "This is my text"

randPos :=  rand.Intn(len(myText) - 1)

newText := [:randPos] + randLetter + [randPos + 1:]
```

But this does not replace the char at `randPos`, just inserts the `randLetter` at that position. Right?

Comment: @tkausl String are immutable?

Comment: With syntax fixed, the code replaces the byte at `randPos` with `randLetter`.  Does the code have unexpected results when you run it?

Comment: I assume the example is a typo since it can't compile at all -- please show the actual code and explain what isn't working as expected.

Comment: right i didnt under sand what you want

Comment: Note that indexing a string may give unexpected behavior when dealing with multi-byte characters, as strings are indexed by byte, not by rune.

Answer (score 1):

I've written some code to replace the character found at `indexofcharacter` with the `replacement`. I may not be the best method, but it works fine.

https://play.golang.org/p/9CTgHRm6icK

```
func replaceAtPosition(originaltext string, indexofcharacter int, replacement string) string {
    runes := []rune(originaltext )
    partOne := string(runes[0:indexofcharacter-1])
    partTwo := string(runes[indexofcharacter:len(runes)])
    return partOne + replacement + partTwo
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A `string` is a read-only slice of bytes. You can't replace anything.

A single `Rune` can consist of multiple bytes. So you should convert the `string` to a (intermediate) mutable slice of `Runes` anyway:

```golang
myText := []rune("This is my text")
randPos := rand.Intn(len(myText) - 1)
myText[randPos] = randLetter
fmt.Println(string(myText))
```